# What am I looking for?

Tags: android

I'm creating a new activity using a linearlayout and I want to make something similar to the stock version of Google Play Music'se tab-like down-arrow buttons (sorry didn't clarify: **the button list of Artist and their album when pressed, NOT the recent/artists/albums near the top**):

I want to be able to have those vertical tab/buttons, which I can tap and it'll pull down it's items, but I don't know what to start with; I'm cross-eyed from looking at all the different ways of trying to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: http://viewpagerindicator.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html). You can style the items just as you would with a normal `ListView` (inflating your own layout for every item). The adapter is a little more complex than an adapter for a ListView, but there's good tutorials.

Comment: Here we go, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Ascorbin!